# How to use the AssertionMiniPipelineAnalysisEngine in cTAKES?

Tags: computational-linguistics, software, negation, ctakes

I am trying to use [Apache cTAKES](http://ctakes.apache.org/) to detect negations in physician notes.

I have loaded the provided analysis engine `apache-ctakes-3.2.2-bin\apache-ctakes-3.2.2\desc\ctakes-assertion\desc\AssertionMiniPipelineAnalysisEngine.xml`
in the UIMA CAS Visual Debugger.

However, when I run it, I don't see any annotation (except one  `uima.tcas.DocumentAnnotation`):

[image]

Why?

I use Apache cTAKES version 3.2.2 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

To run CVD, I've added my `umlsuser` as well as my `umlspw` in `apache-ctakes-3.2.2\bin\runctakesCVD.bat`:

```
java -Dctakes.umlsuser=MY_USERNAME -Dctakes.umlspw=MY_PASSWORD -cp "%CTAKES_HOME%/desc/;%CTAKES_HOME%/resources/;%CTAKES_HOME%/lib/*" -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/%CTAKES_HOME%/config/log4j.xml -Xms512M -Xmx3g org.apache.uima.tools.cvd.CVD
```

I've also added my UMLS username and password in `\apache-ctakes-3.2.2-bin\apache-ctakes-3.2.2\desc\ctakes-dictionary-lookup\desc\analysis_engine\DictionaryLookupAnnotatorUMLS.xml`.

Comment: I think you can get a better answer in Stackoverflow